# How to dynamically update my drivers/etc/hosts file using PHP script for windows?

Tags: php, windows, host, hosts

For windows, I am trying to dynamically edit and update my 'drivers/etc/hosts' using the below PHP code. By this code, I can easily update any file which does not need administrative rights. But in windows, I need administrative rights to open/update host file from this ('Windows/System32/drivers/etc/') directory. Which syntax should I use to open host file with administrative rights in PHP scripts?

```
<?php

 echo "Hi this Host Testing";

 $currentdir=getcwd();  // it will save your current directory location    

 chdir('../../../../Windows/System32/drivers/etc/');  // it will change my 
 web to etc directory (/etc/)

 $file='hosts';
 $current=file_get_contents($file);
 $string_Data = 'Any Data';

 $current.=$string_Data."\r\n";;
 if(file_put_contents($file, $current))
 {
   echo "success in writing";
 }
 else
 {
   echo "fail in writing";
 }

 chdir("$currentdir");


 ?>
```

I am using " ***chdir*** " to change directory but without administrative rights it is not working also.

Comment: You should think thrice about granting an http server which can be contacted from outside the system full administrative rights over your system. There is a reason for the separation of rights. You action will tear down that protection level and expose your system. Never a good idea.

Comment: In unixoid environments there is the ``sudo`` utility for such things. That does not exist for MS-Windows enironments, but there arre rough alternatives: https://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/5-windows-alternatives-linux-sudo-command/

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentdir=getcwd();  // it will save your current directory location    

chdir('../../../../etc/');  // it will change your web directory( /var/www/html/website/)  to etc directory (/etc/)

$file='hosts';
$current=file_get_contents($file);
$string_Data = 'It works success!!';
$current.=$string_Data;
if(file_put_contents($file, $current))
{
echo "success in writing";
}
else
{
echo "fail in writing";
}

chdir("$currentdir"); // it will change directory (/etc/) to your web directory( /var/www/html/website/ )

//change permission before run php page because if your user don't have permission this code can't do writing
```